# How to signIn with facebook in flutter?

Tags: facebook, flutter, firebase-authentication

How to signIn with facebook in flutter? I try like this but nothing appears. Something like the app froze but when I click back drop me 'CANCELED BY USER'.

How to make it work?

The problem is that nothing appears when you click only the application freezes and the only option is to go back and then throw it out 'CANCELED BY USER'.

```
    var facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']).then((result){
          switch(result.status){
            case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
              FacebookAccessToken myToken = result.accessToken;
              AuthCredential credential= FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: myToken.token);
              FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user){
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Menu()
                ));
              }).catchError((e){
                print(e);
              });
              break;
            case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
              print('CANCELED BY USER');
              break;
            case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
              // TODO: Handle this case.
              break;
          }
    }).catchError((e){
      print(e);
    });
```

Comment: have you followed each and every step in this link https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login

Comment: and if application freezes there might be some error what is that